# Maya Python read and set optionMenu value via variable

Tags: python, maya

I have a module that creates a savedSettings.py file after the user used my tool this file is filled with variables to load into the gui next time the tool is used.

I have some checkboxes and a optionMenu. Reading and setting the variables for the checkboxes is as simple as:

```
# loadsettings into gui
if os.path.exists(userSettings):
    sys.path.append(toolFolder)
    import savedSettings

    viewCBvalue = savedSettings.viewCheck
    ornamentCBvalue = savedSettings.ornamentCheck
    renderCBvalue = savedSettings.renderCheck
```

I thought the optionMenu would be the same and wrote:

```
    encodingOMvalue = savedSettings.encodingCheck
```

When I now tell the GUI to use the variables:

```
cmds.checkBoxGrp( 'viewCB', label = 'View: ', value1 = viewCBvalue)
cmds.checkBoxGrp( 'ornamentCB', label = 'Show Ornaments: ', value1 = ornamentCBvalue)
cmds.checkBoxGrp( 'renderCB', label = 'Render offscreen: ', value1 = renderCBvalue)

cmds.optionMenuGrp( 'encodingOM', label = 'Encoding ', value = encodingOMvalue )
cmds.menuItem( 'tif', label = 'tif')
cmds.menuItem( 'jpg', label = 'jpg')
cmds.menuItem( 'png', label = 'png')
```

I get the follwing error:

```
RuntimeError: Item not found: tif #
```

My savedSettings.py looks like this:

```
# User Settings Savefile: 
viewCheck = False
ornamentCheck = False
renderCheck = False
encodingCheck = "tif"
```

Would be great if someone explains me what I am doing wrong and how to set variables for the optionMenu.

Thanks for taking the time in advance and have a nice day coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. instead use mayas internal mechanism, [optionVar](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/optionVar.html), for this.

But if you must do this then know that when you do:

```
import savedSettings
```

- whatever is defined in **savedSettings** is stored inside `savedSettings` so if you have the var `viewCBvalue` then you call it with `savedSettings.viewCBvalue`. You could load this into main by calling `import savedSettings as *`, but you really, really do not want to do this!
- Python import is not a normal function, results get cached.
- Various other problems. Dont use import for this purpose

If you do not want to use `optionVar`, consider using `pickle`